# startActivityForResult new activity immlidately finish make the screen the flash

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

Activity A start Activity B for some data. And B set the data immediate finish. This make the B activity flash for once. Is there any way to prevent the flash?

TextToSpeech.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
intent.setPackage(engine);
startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_DATA_INTEGRITY_CHECK);
```

the engine activity get the requestCode，set the data and finish. This make the engine activity show -> setdata -> finish. What looks like a Activity flashed. Is there any way to prevent this? thank you.

Comment: you can use intent with finish()... for that can you show what you have done as a example...

Comment: `Is there any way to prevent the flash?` what flash? i dont see any flash in your source code

Comment: @GoInterface: post some delay before calling finish()

Comment: Not the most articulate question, but upvoted as I experience a 'flash' of the screen when replicating the above.

Comment: Thank you very much, I find a workaround. Not that good, but worked for me. I will post  it blow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service/Content-Provide instead of Activity if the operation you want to perform doesn't have to do anything with user interface.

Like:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;

import android.os.IBinder;

public class BackgroundService extends Service {


    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BackgroundService getService() {
            return BackgroundService.this;
        }
    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

Call the service from Activity A:

```
startService(new Intent(A.this,BackgroundService.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate() {
    // startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_DATA_INTEGRITY_CHECK);   
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing() && !activity.isDestroyed()) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_DATA_INTEGRITY_CHECK);
                }
            }
        }, 500);
 }
```

I use a delay to startActivityForResult instead call it directly, or it will show a empty fragment and flash out immediately.